# python how to decode http response

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, request, python-requests

i am using the below code to login and retrieve data from an api endpoint  but seems the response see encoded and i am not able to read the content. i am using request requestes-0.0.1

```
import requests
import json
import os


http_proxy  = "http://192.168.10.20:8888"
https_proxy = "https://192.168.10.20:8888"

proxyDict = {
              "http"  : http_proxy,
              "https" : https_proxy,
            }
session = requests.Session()

payloadopt = 'user_id=tom&password=xxxxx'
s = session.post('https://login.milock.com/api/login',data=payloadopt, proxies=proxyDict, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0', 'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, stream=True)
```

response when i print the same on console

```
▒▒7▒E`▒▒YD▒▒k▒샄▒q▒▒f,▒▒G▒(U▒Uv▒4ڍ▒߼w&▒▒!Ψ▒▒▒▒E5Q▒_▒▒{▒F▒▒<.▒▒▒▒4▒▒> p{▒k9▒▒֏9▒▒
```

Can someone tell me how can decode and read the data from the response

Comment: application/json this is what i am getting while printing the header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response is encoded with [brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) compression.  This compression method isn't supported by the standard library. You can install a third party package from pypi to decompress it - a number of packages are available.

For example

```shell
$ pip install brotli
```

```python
>>> import brotli
>>> decompressed = brotli.decompress(response.content)
>>> dict_ = json.loads(decompressed)
```

If you'd prefer to avoid installing a third party module, remove `'br'` from the 'accept-encoding' header in the request:

```
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br' -> 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate'
```