# Wrong encoding (?) in python requests output

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, gzip

Hey I am using python reqeusts. When I perform a post requests with json body to a specific server I always get something like this back (`r.text`):

```
zC�H�@#t��������_6+���Nr��2�T��kfQ.���=�a�
                                          �
�e�$c,��|                                  2�k��ծ��_VJ�{4���D�"DS��W�z��j�Wu�qu��x���8̌B����[1";3[�F13� ��
         8���R�ϡ&
 ��}F������܄/Fa�A���S�����?�aΖ�J9��{ߣ��b��w���Ϊ�I���8}�2���¶m}�"�r�����+V��+�n�'z:}\�3��v��
����U���ߋ�fa��9q�
����;\�������'TɃ��n����/�����>����Q��Ť�7x�����6\`���W�:c�I�@G����]�$�o+�[�~F[�)?����m?�KV}�0�|,�=�s����[lS3쿭~�~q��Ș{ܣ�/�    ��Z�-�No�
                                                                                                     �f���GI�Q7�{�wŰॄo�
_�(��l�a��|/��WT�Q����1��@ݫt��7lE�>��DAL�
                                         ���=z]��$�ǀ��  z¶? ]�W�V7�o��WaX;�.��G�Sg�
                                                                                   �`�[�9R��Om����d���Ǡd��р�3KH�%P��x�88�p������`���Ց���ǳ�d��(�ǌ�~i�p�{���P���
                                                                                                                                                              �P�j�a_.������Z�rQ<�Z��R���94x8t���p  �{3�=��Y0BA\ Oס�w�_0����ް��0;ϙ:�<�jƢ��'.Q
                                                                        ��,��!����`D�#e��X����Z��92���˷��9���xi$�

����1�ɍ����^Om�}@,���n�IK��VE/�"x[��??�
S���)Φ  ,�ӌ           Ռ��S�LM��#��J�~j�8<�~��)LY����7$�Ew�)��k��)��+A��,�wР�>i<�9^J�!&O����',v5�Cǵ�C 7�<�f���=����c��
           ��:>Q,F�u�\z�Ɲ廊���֥�b��                                                                                   �D�k
                                  ���� �M��1k����T��K�����_��T�f�痑?�V)��v��                                             ����`L�d[Xl�/��������R� [�"�<��16��#'l�taE��']�k���S���r���A�b�����r)�                                          ��v�)����{���-m��㍸o��ۆ�W�xU�0��v�g�� w���G�d����9Z<w�����xir����׋?k�T�4M���'����`*���ߞ��                                 ���d��Hss�>�3�Ƚ��A-�W��|�S������Kb�b����2@b\z��d�?��AM�3
����I$�[�y;) ��8q����mVrf�.�Iֽ��'�ɶ�b���诙^�k���u������6��}A�Z�2tՅN��A)�}i.BR�[�럧�Q���S�6>��8o�<���^��M䖈l��3��K��Uˡ>�  +4�f4��������� �ֲ}�;4J    q�/���e,d�3���E����3��ٌ��n�!z<"~�0�K�on����Ԩ��V��s?��?�&q6z�ߘԢ�v4�{F3�.D����<����������"����f�Cl�^�_|��cϐ���#�      ��E��͉�[���R�R\�X�i~��%���T�e-G�/��
�                                                                        ���Xjn��v���}@�W���:�Z0����%�)�
 �S�ֽ4�ÃB]q��wL��4�9���b�,-�J\�%�=p��?v޽�f��8%s��_����MhMm��E��$i�!���k���KJ��}��                        �2ck
�) �V��"�2'X�]Xf�G]༂�s��;��}=���A����<ǎc5t����VFRk�E���'5�ϵS�}�h\��^������B�.9~5q.�o����X�G��E���X|�K��D�`�n��Ӳ��@-�Z9L>����4{��fQ-�m�fs�@���c9�:�e0?ŉ#��2K���U}Nk��]?འ`��LfTM���P+��z~t��Ypi��3��E���I����l���_M`���������������uZH9��nZ���?�:D�mvױ�
                �c��o߱���V��?~@WV�&�_���Z�<�43��F
.�森>�n�dk<�k�����E��϶kzl�OďR��&%+���-�tǡ9,p5�&R9į�./8�u�O�b�l�"��p��8���]G|G_
G�7�m>�ۃ��m�M=�_�����۞�g���@Ug�6y��nO���'J�[o~�������{�<ߗ/l�
```

`r.content` Output:

```
b'\x13zC\x8cH\xcc\x07@#t\xf8\x9c\xf7\xfc\xb7\x96\xff\xad_6+\x9e\xff\xffNr\x8c\xf12\xa9T\xba\xdekfQ.\x88\x80\x88=\xd4a\xbc\x0c\x93\x0c2\xa4k\xb7\xeb\xd5\xae\xfd\xff_VJ\xbb{4\x9b\x90\x16\xea\x08\x90D\x88\x1c"DS\xf7\xbeW\xb5z\xef\xffj\xf9Wu\xefqu\xf7\xe8x\x82\xd3\xec8\xcc\x8cB\xae\xee\x19\xaf\xaa[1";3[\xccF13\xa3\x14\t\x92\x00\x93\r\x90e\x84$c,\x80\xcc|\x0c8\xb6\x8d\xa1R\xcd\xcf\xa1&\n\xc7\x81\xda\x95V\xd5\xcc\x82\xbb\x8f\xd7\xa2\x9d\xc4\xd6IR6\x19M\xc7\\\xf0\x0f\x91\x83\xd0v\'\x99\x04\xd4\x7f}A\r \xdd\xeb}\x15F\xab\xbf\xbe\xfc\xc1\x8b\xdc\x84/\x03Fa\xeaA\xaf\xcd\xfbS\x88\xa1\x9e\x8f\xf1\x98?\xfda\xce\x96\xceJ\x1e9\x0f\xc5\xd2{\xdf\xa3\x1f\x98\xc6b\xe1\xcdw\xfc\x07\x01\xf2\xc2\xce\xaa\xed\x13I\xdd\xee\xe58}\xee2\xf4\xf1\xe6\xb0\xc2\xb6m}\x93"\xadr\xac\x8d\x8a\xf7\x15\xe8+V\xe7\xe7\x8d+\xefn\xbf\'z:}\\\xbd3\xb3\xc9v\xda\xec\n\x08\x08\xa1\xfd\xd5\xfc\x1cU\x9a\x7f\xc4\xc4\xdf\x8b\x9efa\xbe\xee9q\xfc\x0b\xdaKl\x9bzE\xe9^\x97.\xd1[\xac\x98\x83\xfey\xf0\x9f\xf4\x19&&o\x00#\xe5\xb4\xf4&\xa0\xd2\xdb\xde\xc7\x86\xbf\x1ez\xf4U\xc8\x7fa\xf4\xbf>\x13\xfc\x01&p\x03\xe9@\xd8\xf0\xa17\x12\x80\x16\x8b\x83o\x01>\xd3\x12\xfd\xeesQ7 \xe5\xe4\xd3\xfbM\xa5\xf4\xf6\x0f\xa7\x07\x9c\x9d\x8d?\x0e\xdf\x08\xfeE\x9f?\x83\xf8\xed\xad\xf3\xfbo\xae\xf9[lS3\xec\xbf\xad~\xae~q\xce\xdf\xc8\x98{\xdc\xa3\xc1/\xfe\t\xe5\xd1Z\xf8-\xaaNo\xa8\r\xaa\xa6\x98\xf7;\\\x90\xa6\x8f\xf7\xd9\xec\xda\'T\xc9\x83\x9b\xben\xde\xc0\xa7\xa7/\xfd\x86\xa1\xb7\xaf>\xff\x83\xe0\x86Q\xbd\x8b\xc5\xa4\xee7x\xcf\xec\x0e\xd5\xf7\xdf6\\`\x82\x16\xe4\xedW\xf3:c\xa8\x7fI\xb7@G\x91\x95\x0f\x92\x92]\xb6\x7f$\xf8o\x00\x19+\xc3[\xe0\x18~F[\xf0)?\x01\x84\xb2\x8d\xb4m?\x04\xecKV\x7f}\xc10\xcf|,\x86=\xfes\xff\xf7\x17\x0c\xc3f\x13\xdf\xfe\xe7G\x10\x7f\x04I\xf1Q7\xfd{\xe5w\xc5\xb0\xe0\xa5\x84o\xd8\n_\xfd(\x84\x97l\xbea\xab\xb3\x06|\x19/\xe8\xd3WT\xffQ\xad\x1e\xaa\xe0\xcb\x171\x80\xa6@\xdd\xabt\xf5\xe67lE\xc7>\x1d\x84\x04\xcdDAL\xe0\x0c\xf3\xeb\xd5=z]\xf2\x86\xad\xf6$\x8e\xc7\x80\xd9\xed\tz\x0f\xc2\xb6? ]\x9cW\xea\xa2V7\x9fo\x98\x9cWaX;\xfc.\xbc\xe3\x15\x04G\xb8Sg\x86\x0c\xc9`\xf0\x9d[\xee9R\xef\xdeOm\xc8\xd3\xf9\xc3d\xfe\xfd\xe5\xc7\xa0d\xf2\xd0\xd1\x80\x8a3KH\x14\xc0%P\xef\xcb\x05x\x9888\xd9p\xb9\xbc\x19\x9d\x84\xa0\xec\x9b`\xc6\x1b\xbf\xec;\xd5\x91\x06\xcf\xc1\x13\x9f\xc7\xb3\xa0d\x96\x80(\x86\xc7\x8c\xe3~i\xf4p\xc6{\x9f\xa0\x93P\xb6\xfb\x80\x0c\x9bP\xd6j\xd5a\x06_.\x86\x87\x89\xf7\xde\xfdZ\xf9rQ<\x8eZ\xe6\xc9R\x19\xf2\xf8\xe094x8t\xee\xcf\xf8\x12\x12\x05p\t\xd4{\x043\x04\x04\xd3=\x1c\xaa\x87Y0BA\\ O\xd7\xa1\x8cw\xab\x1f_0\xec\xf3\xef\xaa\xf5\xde\xb0\x95\xe50;\xcf\x99:\xd7<\xe0j\xc6\xa2\xb3\x88\'.Q\x0c\xa1\xcc,\x9e\xd0!\xd3\xe9\xe3\xcd`D\x96#e\x8a\xc8X\x8a\x84\x10\xb4\xb8\x18Z\xb7\x18\xf292\xee\xdc\xe8\xcb\xb7\xfb\xc39\xa9\xde\xddxi\x16$\xd5\x0c\x12\n\x9f\xa8\xa6t\xd5,~D\xbe\\\xb4\x0f\x93;>\x1c\xad\xf5\xe7\x1c\x19D2\xfb\x04^\xa8\x0b\x1a\xd5\x8c\x1d\xe0\x92S\xdaLM\x9a\x90#\x9b\x90J\xf7~j\xd4\xc5^\xb4\x99Z4\xf4\xfe\xbe\xfa\xf1\x05\xc3\xd2\xcbh\xcb7lu\x057{U\x0eZ\xfd\xb7`\x98UvXh\xa0O\xd0\xed\x98\x8c\x81\x97.\rS\xcd\x05\xe7\xe3)\xce\xa6\t,\xe6\xd3\x8c\x0b\xdb\x06\xee\x9f:>Q,\x18F\xc5u\xd6\\z\x0e\xf5\xc6\x9d\xe5\xbb\x8a\xaf\xf1\xd0\xd6\xa5\xc1b\xbb\xc8\x0c\xfa\xa3\xda\xd7 \xd9M\xa5\xa51k\x8f\xbc\xd0\xfbT\x84\xacK\x98\xa7\x1bU\x10\xd5\xd6\xdb_\xee\xd1\x05T\x87f\x89\xe7\x97\x91?\x06\xf6V)\xe9\xd0v\x0f\xfe\xb5\x0c\x16\xa7\xd0v\xc9)\x97\xb6\xd5\xc2{\xf2\xf0\xf4-m\xfb\xeb\xe3\x8d\xb8o\xa7\x01\xb0\x1a\xdb\x86\xf8\x08\xf2W\xc1\x11x\x16U\x19\xa10\x8f\xadv\x96g\xf3\x00\x89 w\x98\xc7\xd4G\xccd\xad\x9f\xe7\xf49Z<w\x9a\xa4\xfb\x8e\x06\xbb\x18\x04xir\xdc\xf9\xa4\x1f\xf6\xd7\x8b?k\x1c\xa1T\xf74M\xc1\xe5\xb8\xeb\'\xed\xae\x8b\xec\x91`*\x85\xef\x1b\xd5\xdf\x9e\x88\xa7\n\x1a\xfb\x8c\x8e\xdeeI$\x7f\x91\x0e[\xff\x1cy\x0e;) \xd2\xfd8q\xf8\x90\xae\xedmVrf\xcf.\xb7I\xd6\xbd\xbc\xf1\'\x9b\xc9\xb6\x9db\xdc\xd3\xf1\xe8\xaf\x99^\x9ck\xf7\xb8\xd5u\xfc\xea\xa5\xda\xe9\xd8\x10\xe56\x0e\xa3\xa9}A\xdaZ\xbb2t\xd5\x85\x15N\xf7\xe2A)\xf3}i.BR\x99[\x91\xeb\x9f\xa7\x81Q\xb7\xaa\x9eS\xb46\x0e>\xfb\x02.ho\xfb\xfb\xbe:)\xdaK\xb6\x8c\xca9\xefD\xdd\xd4\xeeE\x95\x07\x94?U\xcb\xa1>\x8b\x01\n\x85\x8b\x1a\xf4Q\x01\xbbY\xd7\xb5bD\xa7\xe7\xddb\x8fGW\x18\x1e\xa8\x16k\xeeX\x9e\xc73O\xc9\x1a\x9d\x0e\x99G\x89\xc0x\x925}v\x82\x8b\xbcN\xc8\x84G\xa9d\xcbm,\xd4\xdb\x98/\xf8\x85\xd6\xcd#\xef\x87V\x8a\xc8\xb8\x03\xf2\x99\xc9&\x99}\xa6\xb7G\x8d\xdc2\x1cd\x9a_\xb6\x10\xef^f\xaf\x1e\xe9e\xd0\xb8\xa7\xa6\xec\x9ek\xe9\x84\xa2\x18\xa8^\x0e\xb3#\xaf\ri\xb5\x1b\x8e#\xbd\xab\xf6\xa5\xf2\xe0\x01[\xee\x16\xed\xcc\x9e\xc4:\xe1w;/x\xb6[.]\xe6}V\x9b\x12Q\xa9e\x19\xec\x14\x97\xa8\x1e\n\x1b\xe5H\x0b\xe1S\xaf\xd6\xbd4\xed\xc3\x83B]q\xf7\xb6wL\xc3\xe44\xd59\x8c\x87\xb6b\x8f,-\xedJ\\\xf5%\xba=p\x8d\x91?\x17v\x19\x0f\x1e\xde\xbd\xcef\xc5\xd58%s\x01\x9e\x9e_\x82\xba\xa4\xfcMhMm\xdf\x06\xc7E\xbd\x9c$i\xe7!\xfe\x95\xc9k\xc5\xdb\xc9K\x01J\xe3\xfd}\xf5\xe3\x0b\x86a\x18\x86aX\xff\x86\xad\xa0\xe5\x8eZ\x96\xcfP`G\x9d\xa7p]\x80#\x14\xd8\xf7\xd5\x8f/\x18\x86a\xd8\x06\'{-\xbd\x10k\xbc\xd6\xde\x04g\xc5\xa9`Q*\xfb:\x11\x95\xed\x94f<\xbe\x9c\xc3m \xbfZ8\xf7\x96v>8\xe8\xd9\x14\xff{GG3\x8cM\x8d\x86\n.\t\xa1&\xe1\'[\xf0\xc6\xf7}\xfb\xc4?\x06[\xcd\xea\xb0<\xda\xf0\xd6\x18k\xdc\xba\xf7F\xc8wR\xdb\x10\xca_K\xd4P\x0e\xc8\x8aB\x85\t\x02\xd5\xd5\xe8\xeb\xe84\xc4\xceq\xad\xe0\x92\xe1\x8f\xebZ\x07H9\x8b\xd5nZ\xc3\xe3\x07\xc9?\xd3:D\xd3mv\xd7\xb1\xc1\r\xe5an]\xd2`\x9a\xe7S|es(\x10\xce\xc5&\xb3\xabg\xb7\x17\t\xaf/\x8f\xfa\xfc\xf2\xbfE\xe3\x19\x07\xcc\xf9I\xe9\x03\xfc\x1e\xf1\x0e\xfdl\xde\xf1\xcf_M`\x9e\xbe\xec\x1d\xb3\x8f\xfd\xee\xdb\xf9\xaa\xa2\x19\xf6\xe7\x9f\xdf\x17\xce\x7fu\r\xf3\xbeoQ\xca\xf7\xdf\xc1?\xb1O1\x97\xfcV\x7f\xa4\xff\x03\x0b\xbec\xbf\xbdo\xdf\xb1\xbf\xb1\xb0\x0eV\x89\x8b?\xea5)\x9c\x08\xdd]\xad\xbd0\nW?\xb0\xc3\xbboG\xee\xf5\xbd\x17$\xdf\x9e\xe0\xdbjn\x8e\xdf\xf1\xbbv\xab\xfd\xa1_4\x96\x15M\xd3\x89\xd5,\xffY\xe1\xfb\xb7i\xbe\xd4\xea\xc7\xc9\xf7\xbf\xb1GLGl\xd9\xb4\xfaW+\x8d94S\xf4\x97\xa0Tq:\xbd7|\xe9\xef\xaf\xdb\xaa.\xde\xfd\xfa\xf6u\x9b\x9bo\xe6\xc545\xb6\x9a\x18\xf7\xdf\x96j\xe5\xf7\xa3\xb6\x82\xa6\xfe9\xe1\xf9t\xd8;\xf6\xf5\xcb\xd2\xd7\xfd\xf4T\x92\xdfc\xb5\r\xc2j\x13\xa0t\xbbf)7\xcb\x97o\xb5M\xb6h[\xb7A\x12u\xcf\x15\xf0\xca\xa2m\xe05}\x90x\xdb\x17\xbe\x92\x11+\xaf\xc7\xc1\xde\xd5G/\xb2\xa8\x1ca\xef\x05\x0bm\xb0\x88L-\x97\xda\x8e\xb1o\x7f\xb6\xbb\xf7o\xff\x86}\xfbsM\xcd\xe3\x07\xe6\xa7\xc5\xfe\xf7\x7f\xb1\xe2#\xef\xef\xef\xd8\xaa\xe0\xc2\xc9\xf6\xc9\x97d\x8fY}\xef\xb0\xc44\x80\r\xbb\xbf\xaa.\x83\x12|H\xfe\xdc\x91\xc7:\xd9\xc5o\xdfw\x8a\x9f\xb9\xf2\xf3\xb8\xc2\xb03\x14\xf5_\xdbK\xc4\xd1\xd7\xe4j\xb6\xe5\xff^B\xce\x82\xa6\xb6x\xfd\xf9\x03y\x16\xe9\xbb\xfa\xe4\x9c\xf6\xc8\x7f\xff\xf7__\xfe}k\xf7\xc7\xf9\xeb\xcb\xeb\xb5\t\x7f\x9c\\\x90\xcb\xb3\xe7\t\xd3\xd7Y\xf3\xab ^\xf9\xb5\x9f7\xa2\xf5\xaa\xc7\xb1\x00\x93J\xff\xe3\x8a\x18^\xa1!\'\x06\xcc\x0f\x96\x82\x05\xaf\x9a\x87O\xcd\x10\xdeVrw\xea^h=\x95\xc5\xaf\xa5\xf2\x9fqG\xfd\xb8\x1c5\xe21s\xcdC\x00\xe9\xd59\x15~y\x8b\xa1\xa9\xa0H\xc6;\xbf\x82\x8cR& <\xb2s\xd3\xff\xb8\x84\x0b\x1c|\xf2T\xa9\x8b2B\x81}\x05\xe4\xa3RR\x8e\xf0\x9c\x1bi\x94\x0cu1\x95Q\x11X\xa4e\n\xa5\x08\x08W3\x94^\xb2i\t\x8fE\xf7\xb0\xa8! \x8d1"\x1e\x8d/\x8f;\x85\xb8\x96P`Gx\x04\x07\x95\xd4@\xe4L\xc5%\x9bF\xf7~\xad\x15Y\xeb\xdc\xbb\xb6\\\xcc\xd3\x12\nl\xaa\xc8\x06\xa3\xe4\x00\x87B0h)\x8bk%\xeca\xca\x12j\xe6\xf6:OM\x8a .\xaa%\x025S\x10\xb4\x8cAK\x01P\xb3`\xd0y@\xa9\x998\xc0\x14L\x90\xa7\x80j\x89\x83\xc6\x83Y\xcd\xec\x1e\x9a\x14\xa9ZF\xaf\xf1\x14\xa9Z\xc6\xa0\xcd\x80T3\xbbW3\xa5\x87&\x18\xe0\x0cf\xd5\xa4\x16\xd5R\x06\xdddG\xd5r\x07h\xb2\x8b\x9a)=\xb4\x14\xa4\x9b\xd4\xa4Z"\xa1f\x06\x823\x05TK\x194\x9e\xa5T\x0b\x0epf\'\x98\x82Y\xcd\x0c\x04SjQ3\x1bi&\x05\x14A\x1ct\x93%\xd5\xcc@\x9aI\xe1\x8a \x0e\xd0d\'5\xcb\x114)B\x11\x8cA\xe3\xd9I\xcd\\\xa4\xa5\x14\x85\xe7\x01hR\xb3j\xeay\'e\xd0L0h\xa6\x1cW\x86\xbdzf\xd1>qQ\x04.S\xad\xf4\x83t\x93%\xd4,\xe8\xb5\x99"\x14A\xbc\xf4\xf2k[p\xd0fvZ\x03\x1b\xe90\xadZh\xd0R<|\xdc\x0f}@\xfe\xc6\x04S\x1b\x1b\t\xfb\x158\xa2\xcd\x80ca".o8ln@\xae\x05\x82\tm\x8bviS\xe0v\'8S\xa4e\xd9s9dy\xbf\xbb\xb0\x1f\xeej\xf4j&\xf6j\x86\xf2\x06e\x84\x0e{&\x05T\xb3=\xc7\xf5\xcb\xd2\x9d4\x1b\xe1\xd0\xd2\xb2\xbaF\x11\xd8\xfd#\xe0\x8b\x13}\x8e\xcb\xb1\xaffvg\xcc\x88\xa1\x91\xfa\x99\x86\xcd4C=\xbe\xfbp\xd0\xe5\xb1\xdf\xfa\x9a\xc9\x0cy\xd6\x15\x87\xff\x17\xbc\x80]\x83\x06\xa8\xdb\xc4Rp=m\xce\xd3~\xc0\t\xed^\xc0\x93\x05v2*\x19\xb4\xf9\x01{\x04\xda\x12`3\x99\xddY\xaf\x00\xfa\x89\x88\xc7,\x9743)B\xd7o\xd1\xab\xd9M\xd1\x04\x17w\xedy\x96\x1d\x03)\x9b\xe5\xfc\xf2Q\xf7;/p\xd0R\x16h<\x1f\x12\xa4l\xd1h\x16k\'\xea\r^\xdcU\x11\xd0\xa0\x9b\x00\xe8x\xb5\xf2\x16\xdaeF\xc0\xb1o\xc8\xb1N\xae\xa6e\x92\xf2k\xe0\x1e\x0f&h\x94\\\xefM\xe3\x0f\xd9\xe3\xa2e\x90\xe3\x8dF\xc0\r\xd8\xf5\x08\xb31if\xc8\xe38\x97\x07.\tL\xdc\x82\x9f\x90\xd7)c9=Y\xe0\xcc\xe50\xdb\xc0l\xbbo\xa4*\x13\x8fAY\xd2f\x1e~+\xd8C\x8b\x1d`\xca\xceZ\x9b\xfd\xdcX\x7f\xebM\x0eed\x9c\xa3\xcf]-"\x9d\xef\xe1G\x14\x04M\xb0\xfc\x1fx\xdf\xe8n\xe4-d\x1e\xd0\xae\xdb\xd0D_\xc1\x16&\xbb\x071&e\x1fL\xc7\x82\xf6G\xbfc\xb0\xe8\xd7\xd3\xcf,ZC*\x82\x9c\x88\x03\xc40\xd2~\x10\xa7~\xa5\xcc\xe7\xb6!\x97\x13\xfa@\xff3<ki\xaaD\xe0W\xd4\xc3\x02\x9d}.\x03\x86\xb7\xe6YZ\xcdN\x9d\xbf\'\xcd\xc1\xa9F=n\x87\x94\x01\x9a\x80\x90\xd5f\xfc\x079b\xc5n\x0f\xad \x8e\x96b,\xb5\xe9_&\xd8\x10~\xef<\xbf\x8d\xc4\xec\x13a\x06\x07\xadr\xd3\x1e\x01G\x85\xe7m\x1f\xa9\xcf\x9f\x17{mW\xb5\xc4\xc9\xd7\xb2\xcd\x94\xbe\r\xe9\x82\xf8!\x9c3V\x0f\'e\x94\x18\xe2\xa4M\xdd\x8c/\xfd\x9e\x1cq\x18\xc7\xb6\xf2^\xe7\xf50\x17K\xa3}L\xe2\x1e0\xda\xce\x91\xc6\xfb\xc6\\\xde\xf1XD]\x932nS\x98\x196c\xff\x06\xc7\x1a\x1f\xb0\x80\x9c\x12\x8f\xf0\xff@\xc4UC>\x12\xa6<p\x88\x06\xd6\xdbA\x0f\x97x)\x1c\xa2M \xb7\xb1|\xedMwB\x83.\xc2\x05.6\x87\r\xb7\xe0\x02\xd3\xfdk8\x8fs\x88\xf5\x88\x03\x15\x8b\xeb\x8edfL\xa5>\x12/a+K\xf5\x0c\xeeX81\x01\x9e?\xb4\x88\x83\xce\xb3\x1b\xfa8\xa8\x91\xee\x00\x9d1\xee\xa4\xc9\x8d\xd3\xf0\xb1\xc8\xc7^Om\x90}@,\x11\xff\xb9\x9en\x82IK\x81\xcfV\x0f\x17E/\xea"x[\x90\x02\xe5?\x1c?\xe0\x0b8\x16<\xc4~\xf4\xa5)LY\x9f\xb4\x99\xcf\x127$\xa6Ew\xcc)\xf2\xc2k\xb4\xed)\x87\xee\x86+\x02\x1c\x15A\xe1\xec\x99,\xd8w\xd0\xa0\xcb>i<\xff9^J\xdc!&\x1cO\x9c\xe4\x10\xe2\xa9\xf0\',v5\xfbC\x1c\xc7\xb5\xecC\x13 \x187\xe2<\x1e\xd2f\xb5\xdb\xfb=\xfd\x8e\xfc\x1d\xeac\x0f\xfc\xc5\x0c\xceD\xe0k\x0b\xf2\x8c\x91\xc0\xcb\x03\xfe`L\x82\x1fd[Xl\xb5/\x0e\xba\x8c\xec\xb0\x05\x06\xe8\xe8\x12\xc0\x03\x0f\xe4\x1c\x98R\x80\t[\xa4"\x88<\xa1\xf116\xaf\xc0#\'l\xf5taE\x1c\xfb\x02\x85\']\x97k\xa4\x97\xe1S\x9b\xff\xder\xe9\xcf\xc9A\xbdb\x00\x87\xa3\x1e\x1f\xd1\x0e\xac\x1f\x9fr)\xf8\x0c\x1b\xb3\xf5\xdc\x00A\x1ed\xef\xf5Hss\x1c\xf0>\xc53\xa5\xc8\xbd\xfd\xd9A-\xb0W\x95\xfb|\xceS\xb6\xd6\x11\xf9\xde\xc0\xbb\x12Kb\xfe\xce\xa2\x08b\x1c\xc4\x0e\xdd\xfb\x902@b\\z\x02\xb5\x9ad\xb8?\xb5\x92AM\xc33\x0b\xed\xc28o\xea<\xa8\xb1\xbd^\xcd\x1e\xb5M\xe4\x96\x88l\x8e\xf63\xec\xefK\xc0\x12\x94\t\x7f+4\xf2f4\xfd\x1b\x99\xac.\x81\xb6A\x1f\xc1\x1f\xfc\x06\xbb\xce \xba\xd6\xb2}\xf1;4J\tq\x02\xb9/\xb8\xa9\xd2e,d\xcd3\xe6\xd3\xccE\x9c\x8f\x1c\x10\xe7\xc03W\xccA\xc4\xeb\x94\xb2=\xb9K(\x82k\x07\xfa%@?G&\xcb\x85\xc4c\xd8L\x0e\x16\x9d\x15\x81\x9d\xa9 lL\x90\xf7\x03\xe7\x9b\xbb\x8c\xf6\xc74\xbcF\x8f\xa0N\x9a\xecV\xe3\xe7\xc8\x9dqWx\x9b\xfbI\x9c&R\xa7qD2\xc6=E\xbf\xb9k#\xeaA\xb4\xa8Cl\xc2\x82\xee\xa3^\x87_|\xbe\x82c\xcf\x90\xbf\x80\xad\t\xf5\xdfE\xb7\xb9\xcd\x89\xf4[\xfa\x9a\xfcR\xec\x19R\\\xdaX\xc4i~\x88\xa7%\xcf\x11\x9b\x80T\x9fe-G\xe4/\xea\x04\xf8\r\xce\xe5\xd9\x8c\x1b\xcer\xcdn\xe0!z<"~\x8f0\xe6\xa8K\x9con\xae\xc2\xd2\xef\xd4\xa8\xbd\xb9V\xe8\xdes\x16?\x84\x03\xa0?\xb4&q6z\x0e\xfc\xdf\x98\xd4\xa2\x93v4\x07\xe2{F\x113\x1b\x84`.D\xcb\x04\xb0\xaf\xd6<\xfb\x9b\xf5\x86\xa5\xbd\x0f\xbc\x87\xed\xc4"\xd1\xc9\xd4\xd1f\xaf\x0b\xcb\xea\xe6Xjn\xfc\x1c\xe4v\xfe\xbb\xd9}\x16@\x1c\xc1W\xf4\x9f\xb9:\xafZ0\xba\x18\xe2\xc1\xff%\xec)\xce\x0b\xc02ck\n\xba) \xde\x02V\x11\x03\xa0\x97"\xde\x032\'X\xca]Xf\xbfG]\x19\xe0\xbc\x82\xbfs\x1f\xe2\xbd\xce;\x0e\xfd\x19\xe5}=\x05\x82\x97\x86A\xfe\xa5\xc6\xca<\xc7\x8ec5t\x1e\xf1\xc8\xdc\xfa\x01VFRk\x86E\xff\x12\x07\x03\xa1\xf1\xb1\'5\x8a\xcf\xb5S\xa6}\xf6h\x1bq\\\xbf\x0f\x94^\xaa\x01\xfd\xcc\xf8\xd1\xf5B\xed.9\x16~5q.\x85o\x88\xc1\x95\xc0X\xe0G\xb6\xaaE\xab\xdf\xc4\x12\x1cX|\xafK\xa8\x93D\x9b`\xa1n\x9c\xb6\xd3\xb2\xb9\xc9@-\xe5Z9L>\x8c\x94\xfe\xfc4{\x9c\x91\x08\x18\xb3fQ-\x8d\x14m\xec\xdc\x82\x08fs\x1e\xb1@\xb8\x91\xf5c9\xc6\x06:\xf7e0?\xc5\x89#\xb0\xe22K\x92\xe7\x89\x07\xa8U}Nk\xbd\x19\xe0]?\xe0\xbd\xa0`\xeb\xfcLfTM\x86\xa1\x97P+\x13\x8a\xf4z~t\xca\xeaYpi\x9c\xb23\x0b~\x0f@WV\x06\x89\x7f&\xd8_\x03\x9c\x1bT\xe7\xe4Z\x18\xf1\x8c<\x8f43\x8b\xd7F\n\xd3\\@G\xe6\xbd=\x80a\xf6\x81Xz\x01\xad\xeaV\xf7gK3\xa068\'\xe7}&5;\x11{m\xd6\x9a\xb0\x00\xea\xc6`c\xb5\xd4G\x1c5\xaa\xea@s\xb9\xa9\x07\xce\xd8\xf3\xf0\x81\xa9\xa8\x7f\xeaQ\xf0Y\xa1\x15\xa9\xeb*\xdc\xdb\x07\xf1\x08n^t\xfe\x85\x8ew\x1f{\x12\x98\xf5\x92\x85s\t\xb8\x81\xbd\xc0<d\x1fW\xec\x95\xfe~\xc3\xf0\x83\xe0\x8f)1I\x99\x11\xdf\xb8\xe4{k\xf1\x04T\x87\xd4\x0c\xb4\xab\xd8G\xf4F\xf0\xe7\xd61\x80\xfaRt\xf4\xa5%*\x01\xae\xa7n2\xa85\x92\xb2\x19Z\xfa\xc8,\xcdT\x83y\x16\x82o\x98c\x86v\xbd\n\x07\x07q6\xaf\xac\xa0FT\xbb\x91\x93d\x9ew\xd6\x0f\xd1\n\xd4{\xf4Af\xa4\xc2\x97u\xa2G$c\xb8W\xd2\xbb\t\xcek\x98\xade\xd6\x04\x9e$v\x89\xf5\xc4\xb7\xe0\xfc8\xd3\x84\xbc\x0f\xf8\xde\x9c\xc6\xea\xcf\r\xe1\xf1:\xbc\xbafvZ\xda\x87\x05\x17-M\xdf\xdb\xf3\xf2:\x18R\xba\xe5]d*\x07\xb6\xf8\x97\x9a+\x04s\xc1\x01\x80p]x\xc4\'\x12\xf7\x1c\x82E8\x9bX\x8f\xbd\xa3\xed\xd7 \xe8/\x1f%M\xc1&\xe3\x15\xdcZ\x82\xdd\x91~\xb73kj\xde\xd19\xfd\xa9-\xe5\xcc\x90\xe6\xce5\xdd\x8f\\R\x8b/\xcd\xdf\xef\xbfX\xbc\x9d\xa5\xabg\xc9\\Ln\xd4yV\xef\xc5\xe4\xbebq.[~\xf3.\x87=\x93\xcf\xa8\xf0-\x8aw^\xe3\xb0\x8b\x81\xde\xc1\x04<\xa6\x11\x9c\xb9p\xef\xd2\xae\x91>\xbeF\x9d\xfc\xae\x89s\xfdG\x17\xd5\xcaQ\xcd\x9d\xd3e\xf4\x19r\xb6:\xd7\x9f\x1akh\xf9.\xa5\xd9J0S\xc8\xeai\x9c\x19\xa1\xbd\xb6\x8a\x0c\xa6\xb3\r\xb5w>\xb3\x8a&\xf1\x99\x93\x9c\xfa-\xc7\x119\x93\xb3\x85p|%Rw\x84\xe4Hh\xc02\xff\x9e?\xfb\xa9\xd8\xdbS\xce\x97\x88\xee\x92\xf3\x9b\x8350E\xbb\xbb\xae\xcf\x82{\x9f\xc9\x19\xb2\x97\xf3\xef\xf8N\xfd\x18f]\x89\xfb\x05\xf2k\x98l\x04&Xp\xee\x1a\x1e\xe7\x18U\x04\xe2\x94\xe4\xce\xef\x82;\x90#\xf6%\x9e\x8f\xb3\xed\xbe\xbc/\x9fUxLo@\xc8\\\x04\x8d\x80\xfb\x9f\x91\xce\xeb\x05\xe0^\xf6O0\x7f\x954\x0b\x9cv\x1bM\x1egU\xdeQh\x1f\xe8=a\xd7\xd0^=\xfbV6\x98\xa1\xe0\xf2\x1e9O\xb5\xcc\x8a\xf9n\x98\xf5k$\xfec~\xe4\xd9\x95\x05\xe3G\xac\xe4\x1d\x07\xf0_\xee\x82\x95\xf7\xe3\xf8n\xfb\xb3\x89z\x8d+\x8e]o\x91"\x0e|\xe0\xdf\x8a\xf9&q\xd6\xcd0\x0eD\x06G\x88\xbb\'\x03\xe9e\xca\x97\xc0\x1b\x07@\xecEb!\xa2\x87\xf3\xd8\x88,S\xfd\xdf\xa9>\x8f\xb3~\xc3cp\xc8\x1dt\x19\xf4\x18(\xf5\xd9\x1d)\x83i\xfb\x04K&\x0e\xa3z\x1e\xfb\x18\xe5\x88\x0c\xe5q\xaes$\xbfa\x07\xdc\xc8\xde\xb8\xc2\xfb\xa9\xff\xb3/K\x11?\xc8\xae\xa9\x9bI}\xa0\x97Q\xaf\x9ar\xbd\x8e1\xd9\x12\xe7\xc1\xbb6\xa6!y\xde\x0eoat\x16~\xdd\xcf\xdd\xc8W~&F2gc\xab\xed\xccq\xe7\x93\xdc|8K\x9c\xf9\xad\xce\xf3\xf6\xf6:\xb1\x0e\x98\x9f\xe2b\x8a/\x00\x13\x84\xfe\xad\xf8\x0f\xf4\xd0\xa1\xf9\x95\xe9\x82F\x079\xbf\x94\xf1\n\x9d\xddy\xdeG\x9e+X\x86\xcat\xc1Q\x03\xc0\xfa\\l\xbb\xd8\xf0\xe4\x97\x8a\xd7~T\x194g\xacs\x00:T\x14u7\xe9s\xc5r\xb5\xfdH\x13]\x9e+\xd8\x06\xca\x0c:\xafg:\xd2\x81\xd8\x9a*\xbb\x04\x9bI\x9a\xa0\x1b\x8c\xc0"\xa3|<n\x1c\xaf\x94m\xec\x03\xf2\xe3.\xff\xb3\x1d\xcb\x83\xce$t\xc0rC\xfa\xb3\xd6\x8f\x01\xbfG\xdbL\x8f\xd3\xd8\x88\xa0\xcb\xe3q\xf8d\x8f\xbf7Rg\x948\xe4;\xc42s\xb9\xe0\x81^\xc9\xfa\xedMj\x96\xd4\xfcq\x85\xa3\xdf\nN\x13\xed\x10\x0cL\x0bc3\xbb\x86<\xceB\x0f\x9f\x9c\x04\x8d\xe7U\xec2\xb7\xc6\xf1h.\x0f\xa8\x91\xc6s\xb7)xt\xe5\xb3\xe8\x80\xe0}\xf8\xde\xd1\xf5F\x10\x9c{\xac\xf0\xfa\xed\xaa\xab\xae/\x18\xbf\x86\xb0\xe0\xf2\xb5A\xcb\x8c\x9e+\xe3(\xcc\xb2\xc7\xd8\xfeS\x1b,\xbaX&\xea\xb2\x11\x1e\x0fV\xf5x;Mwi\x19<\xb2\x04:p\xe81\x97\x1b \xda\xcb\x81\x9a\xbbx\x14\xcf\xda\x96\xce\xf3\xd1\x80th\xb4Iq\xb7\x9d\x94\x9dt\x8c\xaf\x1c1<\x99/\x01&\t;\x9av?\xf8#\xe6\xb1x\xdc\x83\x863\xe7\xe3\xa33\xd9\xd3\xb9~%\xf8u\x16\x02\xa5\x13\x8c\x1f\x99\x1e\x01ZPl_y\xb0\x89v\xbe\x13\xfc\x046\xb7Y2/\xb8\xfclf\xd9h\xac\xcb|\x1b\xc6(\xcb\x1f\x064I:\xbc"-\xbe\x8f3=\xea\xdc\x9f\xea\xabq\xe1#2\xbeU\xb7\x99z\x02\xac\xa3\x1e_\xa1\xedG\xb1\xd3X$\xff&}\xb1\xde\x9c\x1f\x89P\x1f\x8d\xc1\x98\xc1q.0o\x9d\xa3 \xde\xa5v\x10ewX\xfa!(\xf6\x96\xd0\xb3\xd6\x91y\x0ei\x9bex\xa7\x8b5\xe0s^\x1d\x84c1\xcd\x859\xbcc\x9ab\xe7F\xf4\xa9\xcc\x1b\x96\xae\xbd]N8\xe9X\x93\xf5\xe8\xcf\x08\x07\xdd\xc1\xf8N\xa3\x89V\x8e\xb8\xfce\xd0\r\x17\xda\x0eKZ\x88x\x1c\x863\x9a\xacs=\xd4\xe1\xe6l\x1c\xb17\xf1=p$\x1d\x1br\x9c\x0e\x0cZ\t\x16\xdd&\xb4\xb9\x8ct\xab\x8f\xcd\xc8\x9dm\x05)\xbf\x98S\xe5\xbc\xae\xd0\xa6\xe0\xc4J\xc7\x95.\xd3\xac\xe3\xf6iC6\xfd\x98F~\x8c\x93HW.\xa5\xd9\x93\xa99/\xa2|/\xbe\x17\xccH\xc7\xa4\xf6W\xc0\xf3\xc7\xef\xc7a\x87\xfd\xd4\x1a16\xcc\x97\x97\xa0\xe9\xe0\x94}\xeb[\xa6\x8cQ\t\xf4\x82M\xd2]0p\xda\xb3q\xc6P)+\x05\xc3\x8e\xca\xdfHK"\xef\xa8/\xd4\xc9\xf2s\xc9\xfe\x9d\xf8\x99\xf0\x06\xe6\x1b\xe71\x17\xa8\xfcA\xd7)\xe9\xe5\xf7\x0e\xe4)\x02\xf7A\xd9\xd1\xce\x87\xf3\xd8Yp\xfbf#D\xc8\xd7\xf8\xb7\xec\x86q\x03\x1e\xa2]\xaf\xe8\xceu\xb9}\xad\xf3\xe3\xc2Ox\xfc\x197\x0b\x1fE\xa9\xbaPk$>N<\x16\xea\xddocF\x00\xb06$m\xbd\xef\xe7\xfe-"\xb8\xb3\xe6\xf1\xeb\xabi\xe4G-\xc6E\xdd\x10$\xc1\x7f\xc4*\x9b\xfb\x0e\xf6\xe9\xf7\xf1\x87\xe0u\x18J+\x84\rU\x87\x15Q\x1aF-\xb6\x0cX\x17$UT\x14?1\xbb<\xed\x8d\x1f\xd2/C\xec%mTaC\x15b\xab\x91~\x04\xc6V(\xf2\xeb>\xc2^u\x85yA\x0cJf\xf0\x8bEIT\xfd\xc0^Q\xfb\xaa\x8b\xa2\xeb\xff\xff\xff\xaa0EW\x9fh\xa6\x11\xe6\xa7}\xb8+VyA\x12\xd7\x05:u\x88i\x87\xf1\xab\x97\xca\x9fU\xc5\xf7X\xe6T,\x84)\x16@\xe1/\xe2@\xb2\xf0\x1ek\xbao]W\xef\xabm\x18\xf9\x15\xd5\xdb\x0fo\x8f\x83\x9b"\xed\xa3M\xef_\xf4]9\xbe\xcd\xd3n\x93Vy\xb19\xe7\x83\xbe\xf1\xa6\xf9\xc9i\x856C\x15n\xc8MYW^\x1fmR\x8b\xcf\xc9\x0f\xdf\x94i\x8f\x8a4\n\xbb \xf1\xe2~S\xad"\xdf\xac\xc2:\xe6\x8f\xcc\xeb\xaa\xab\x8b\xa8\xda\x10{\x00p\x12,\xd1\x19\xff\xfd\xb1\xd6H\x17g\xfdM>\xfa\xfc\xe3\xe3=\n\xe2 \x044\x13\xd1\xf1.\xd83!E\xc41\xed\xe3\x1eC\x1c\x08\xe0\xedb\x9f`\xa2\x00P\xe4\x06\xdf\x81\x1d\xe3\xd0\xf5\xbfq\x87\r\xd8\xb0\xde\x9dq\x1e~NT\x1f<\xdd\n\xf3\xb1\xd9\x8fC\x82\x9a\xfc\xae+\xf4\xe5P\x98\x87*\xd9\xddX\xa5\xce\xc5G\xa7\x9c\x18\x82\xf5\xc6\xb6\xfa\xe8\x18\xffe+\x81QD9\x89\x9b\x07\x97\'(`l\xba}\xe1vB\x92.\x82\xa5\xe5\xc3]\xa2R\xb9O\xe3}\xc5M\x1d\xf9\xd8\xe9}a1\x1f\xfe\x0e\xb9\xf2\x85;9\x887\x18z3d\xcf\xfd\xde\x8d\xeea|\xcc\xfc\xdbb\xbc$\x1c\x9d\xe1\xe6x\xc13b?O\x96 \x15\xd4\x18\x1c?\xcc\x99\xab\xe5\xec\xd0\x061\x92>n\xd6n\xf7\xdaD/\xf40Sn,Y\xebuI\xd9qc\xde_Df\xd4a\x9c(\x0cks\xd6&=\xce\x12(\x8d\xe3\x806x\x10\xd2\xc3\x87\x92r\xb7\xf4\x90M\xdcX\x14\xc87\xe7}}j+\xbf\xcf-\x81\x1f\xa8\xe3+\xedw\xc0;\xd4\x8e*\xce\x92d\x17\x81&\x17\x19\xa0\xcb\xae=\xe6\x14\xfdAzB\xba\x08x(\xcf\x10=\xa7\'\x98\x1eOJ\x9aZ\xdc\n\x0f`V"\xe2\xd4\xdb\x8e\\5~\x1a\x93h|\xb2\xd9>\xec+\xbf\xec\xcf\x16\xce\xe9C\x80\x0e\xd6eb}\x86H\xee\xaf\x83!ofI\xb2\x86\xe6hxRHw\xf1\xdd9\x8c\x91\xbd\xc1U\xffRv\x87^u\xea\xeb\xcd\xf1w\x96\xfbq\xd9\x84\xbdP#r/\r!\xd0h\xaa8\xba\x92x0C@\xca:\x7f\xe3\xd2\xfc\xe3D\xb4\xac\xd67\x9b\xf0\x91\xf9un\xf5,\x03\xe3\x01\xea\x12\xe7\xb5\xd3\xfd\x19\xd8\x07\x993H\xb9\r\xe7\x13\xc7\x97\x1f\x94pO\xd0\x87\xb4\xcc\x03=-6\x15P\xd7x\xc4\x89 \xb8o\x86A\xc4E\x04D`#^\xbd\x97\xb6\xdc\xd9\xf7"R\xa9!J\x1b\x7fb\x1a\xa0\x1f\x0b\xbb\x92\x88E\xbf\x91W*\xe5\xc2s\xfe\x18\xfd\xd6n\x9b]\xb4y\x9d\xf7\x8bd\t\x93\n\xbaY\x1f\xab\xc3\x81\x16E\xc3\xbfY\x99\x17I\xca\x04\xfa\xe3\xcd{\x1c\xaea\xd4\x14z}\xf6\x0b\xd8\xa3\x03}=\x05\'\x9f\x93x!\x07NI\x85\xb3|\xdc\x0ff\xa3\x94Z~\x9f\x93\x1bc\xd4P\xa98\xc1h\x8b\xdd\xb1T\xb2\x94j\x05\x9c\xd8\xc7O\x1c}x\xa5\xaa\x08\xa9\xfaH\x02<\xa7G)\xbe\xe8\x99\x16@\x89\xe3\xa7!\x11\xf6Okt\xc7{\x06\xbb^k\xf0\xe5\xa3\xc2ib|\x9a\x11h\x1f\x1762\xb9\rD\xdc\xab\xc2\xabr6\xadW\xce\xae\xb02\xea\x93:|_]t\xd3ZaQ\x15\xf4s\x13\xbd\xaf\xbc\xa6)\xd2\xc09\xe7\xd0v\xda\x8c\xe3\xc8\x14v7C[x\xd0\xd2\x95\x84\x8c\x8f\x8b\xeb\x8e\xa6\xe1\xfb\xd7 \xde\xb8\xb4\xddj3zi\xff\x95-\x16qn\xea\x9aps\x15\xb5\x7fl=\xbc\xe2U\x10o\xfc\xc1\xf7\x8b\xa8[q\xd3%l\xe5^\x11Ky\xf3\xeb2\xee\xfc\xaf\x16\xdc\xa7\x06[\xfa\xe7\x1b\xef\xca#\x85\xd7G\xef\xabV\x0f>\xcaUs\xb4\xb1s=2Z\xfd\xe5eG\x97\xc2\xe7`\xfe|\xc9\xca\xbfb\x11ac\x84\x9d5\xdd*\x89<+\xc5\xabR\xdd\xe9\xe8\x13\xb9\xba\xa9\xcd\x8b\xf9\x82a\xeeup\x8d\x1b\xb6\xfew\xff\xb2h\x8a\xa6\xf7\x8c\x0f\xa8\x80\xa4b\xcfg\xc2xG\xedq*\x8ewA\x10\xed\x0et\x0c\xf0`\xe7\x054c\xfc\xff\xba0\x9f\'=\xf6\x03\xaa\x95\x9eSlj\xdc\xb9\xde\xfa/a\x89\x1fF\xb63\x8e\x86\xd0\t\xde\xc4S\xf5z\x16X\xb3%\x82\xd7\xf3\xda\xa6\xfa\xac\x95\xd9| \xbc\xf9\xb5\'\xfb\x1b\xe4yo\x1f\x87\xfe~\xbfu\tS?\x0cm\xe9\xd7tr\x03\xfa\x90\xac\xb5\xd1\x81\xf537\xe6\x92o\x1e\\P\x92\xfb\xd2\x92\x0c\x87U\xf3K\xdb1\x92\x03\n\x8e{\xba\x17.\xba\xd7\x85V9HSqM\xbeN A\xe0\xd8\xd9\xd6\xbex\xc1\xf5\xb5\xbd\xc0\xe0&\xceKj\x84\x8b\xe2Xj\xc6Z[\x16G\xe5\xb8\x04f\x9e\x05y\xcc*\xdb\x1a%[\x10\x91{\xfa\xf5P\xca\xb5(\x89m\xb3,g\xdb?L\'t#\xf8\xbb\x91\xd6;^\xb0w\x8eR>\xa5s \x9a<UZE[\x04\xb5Ki\xb9N\xe0MG\xae\x01.\\;\xf5\xd0\'ty|\x8d\x19\xcb\x85\x14s\x8f}Qx\xf9\x13P\x9eu/\xaf)\xd6\xcc*\xe8\xd0\x83\'\xd23\xe4t\xfa\xee\xed\xfdCB\xee\x99C\xbc\xa5\xecJq:\xb1tD\xb5\xf2y\x86\xe9\x0f\xb7\xebt\x8d\xa6\xcb\xce\x92\xba\xe0\x8e3\x0e{9s\x9cb\x11\xfbQL4V\x92\xce\xa0X\x86v\xcbK\x8e\xc7\xf7\x83x0\xc9\xddq\x96\x83\xc1\x16ks\xec\xf7\xa0<\x04\x07\xe8\xaf\x870\xa6\x19\x07iW\xd8fgd(L\xa8f\xd3\xb2\x94:\xe54\x95\xb5\x8d\xa9\x8bo\xae\x9f\xbb\xde\x8do\x8f\xf1~\x89\x1bJ\x7f\xac\x85\xf1tI\x9f\xb7r\x1a\xf1\xf5u\xb7\xd8~+\xe8\x87\xbd\x0e]\xc5WuOv\x0b\xd2\xb8\x07\xd6\xe2\xdd\xef\xf5r?\xf6\xeb,\x81\xc9\xa4\x8b\x9d\x1c=[!\xf1\x12d\x91\x97\xd3\xf1\x11\xb5K\x15\x9d\xc9\x1b\x8bSL\xbe\x1f.\xe4E\xb2\xed\xed\x91\xf5\x19\xdf\xda\xc7\x8fW=D{\x9c\r\xdb\xce\n\xb3:\x92\xc8[\xa7\x9ai{;wa\xd6\x12!\x19v\x8e\xb9W4\xdd7=2~\x14\x9a\xbe\x8e\xc2:<\x85~a9\xb0\x9b\x11\xe4\xc9\xd1\xde\x8a\x97\xd3\x9a\x1aw$\xbe\xeb\xd4VR\x08\x86\xbb&\xebcs\xaf\xd2\x83\xbf\x04\xd7\x9d}\xbb9\x86@v\x8f\xf8&F\xa2\xba\xef-5\x1fj{\xd9\x91\xf5\x11\xc5\xf4\x8b\x9d\x17\xd7P\xe7\x81\xdb\xd1]r\xb9\x9f\xf0\x8e\xa3\xa2P\xa6d\\\x17\x1dh\xa4;\xdb\xf1Fv\xcb+u\x1d\xc2\x16,#d/\x1c\xc5\x19EjO\xd7.{\x84\xc6\xfa\xceu\xcf\xeey\xe3\xb8\x98i{\xfbF_\x8a=\xf9R\xb3\xe5\xb2\x1b\x99\xeb\x95a\xc1\xf5q\xa7\xac`{\xa3\x9f\xc6\x99F\rOOWG\xdbjk\xb2\xdeE\xd9\xc1\x98F\x11\xe5W\xe9fS\xe5\xd1\xa8-\xa7Sj\x97:\xb6\xaa\x83\x02<\xbc\x84\xb7\x19\x8f\x8d\xc7\x9ay\xe0w\x8597\x8e\xcf.>\x8d\x9f\x1fsO\xe9mB\xde\x87D\x8c}\x92\x00\xd5\xe9%.\xea\xe1\xbeM\x94S\x0f\xe92X\x0e\xd4\x90\xd0\xdd\xc2#g\xe4\x1f[J\xa5\xdc\xe0\xf4`\x0f\xc7hKM\xa6\xa7\x17\xeeT\x9c{g\xad\x81\x8cv\xba\xf9\xa8\xd6\x02|\xf4/\xb2oo\xeb\xac|\xa4\x03A\xe8\x87r|\x86\xb74y<\xb5\xbb\xd6\x99\xed\xf1\xea\xb1l\xb9?r\x8d\xa2\xac\xc5\x93d\xe9\xe6Q\xd7\x1f\xfb\x18n_\x1a\x89b-0\xbcN\x1e\x9d\xfa\x16\xf2|v\x8f4y/\xe0\xa1\xce\x9c\xc4\xfd].O>\x04\x91-\xd9\xecK\xd9\xef=zA;k1\xafNp:2/\xeb\x0ey[,d\xba\xaa\xe8\x93\x12\x04\xae\xd7\xd0%\x1bi}MG\xd0>\xf5O\xb0m\re+\x1el\xe3.!\xb0\xf3(i\xd2^Z\xa0i\x13\xad\xdeDF\xb1.\xa2\xce\x85N\x16\xed\xa5r\xb9,\xe1\xd5\x98\xb8\xabs\x0e\xb6\x9cYt\xfbFH\xec-!KN\x8eJ\xef\xd1\x90V\xda\x8dL\xd5\x0e\xfeI[_\x01\x1fd\tS\xb7\x86\x95\x0b\x05\xc0\x9f\xbcI\\Z\xdf\xc9v\xe6\x13\xf7@e\xb8F\xccQ\xd7\xf0\xae\t\x05#\xdc\x90\x9b\xb2\xfd\xad<Z\x84=\x1e\xf2e"\xb3x`f9`\xb9x\xbd\x1bc\x08\xdaf\xde\xado\xf8\x94\xeb\x96\xa3\x1f\xc5\x86\xae\xb7\xc72\xd1\x06\xba\xb9\xc8\xd2A\xb2\xab)s\x1eL\xa0r\x9d\xb9\xe7p\xbdI\xc6\x07g\x1eY_<X\xa1\xa9_\xa9\x8e\xbd\xf0\xecU{\xec\x80\xd9\xc9\xd6\xe9f\xd9>n\x9c\xbd\xae\xf1oI\x8c\xdb\xf7\xc7\xfe\xdaqyt\xa3\x0f\xa3\r\xcbm\x9cu\xf63\x1c\x0e\xe5pdk<\xcfk\xb7\xe0\xc8\xea\xae\xf7E\xa3\xf1\x17\xcf\xb6kzl\x80O\xc4\x8fR\xf4\xc4&%+\x13\xdc\xcf\x02\xee\x96-\xd5t\xc7\xa19,\x11p\x145\xaf&R9\xc4\xaf\xbb.\x11\x13/8\x07\xe4u\x81O\x9ab\x18\xd0l\xff"\xf4\xd2\x1a\x1cp\x0e\xb5\xf68\xb5\x91\x97]G|G_\x04\n4\n\xdb,NjFxz\xbf\x0f\x17\xa9\xb2\xb5s\xe2\xedF\x9d\x8f\x8e\x17Z\x97\xb7.<\xd1\xebJ\'\x9f\xdc\xe5`Y\x1e{:\x1b\xc4\x9d\x02\xfb\xd0\r\xf8\xd1\xa2[\xa2J\x1c\x8e\xa3\xec\x8e\x91\x8d\'KD3\xbc\xefu!\x9b\x9f\xe1\x81\xa9N\xbb\x0bG{\xa7\x0e\xf5\xf7\x89=P\xbeC\xdb\rI\x1c\x0cy\xdf\x9f\x9e3\x11\x8f\xf9\xfc\x14\x9f\xeb\x8eq\x81\x91-\x1c\x1c\x9f\xa70b\x16u\xdf\x80\xe6 >$\xf9io\xedCmU\xc3\xb9%v\xdd\x1dE\xa7\x8b\xde[\x8b4\xaf\xe9;\x0b\x04\xdf\xa2\xf9\x97\xbc-hq\xb8\xa8\xc3\xdeb\x95\x17\xcfx\xe8\x01\xc6F\x95\x9a)_\x93\xf6\xb3y>$\xdb\xd5\x1d\x91\xdfRF\xdb\x8c\x9d!f\x9a\xbf\x0f\xcf\xa4\x91\x9dvD[\xeeK\xa9q\xa8`1q\xa7$\x17b\xa4^V3\x945\xf3B\xc2i\xf5\x97<\x86\xb9\xa2\xa6\xca\x87\xf2\xb4\n\xa5\xf3SIV\x89/\xbe\x82\xf8\xbf2\xe31\xd1\xce\x8f"/\xdeG>\x15\x1fp\x9c>\xec\xc8\xd8\xdbE~Hz\xdeA\x19k\x9f\xc9\xd7\\\x13\xd1\xd2\xcb\x8d\x83\x7f\xe1\xc8\xd0\xfe\xbbl\r\x80\x1c\x1e?\xc1\xd5\x1b8.\xdd\xe6\xa3\xae>\xb2n\xe7\nu\xe1\xbe\xad\x1f\x12\x14\xb1\xfb\xa5\xd8 \xf6\x12v\xc6dk\xacv\x85\x96\xfd\x10\xda\xff\xe0\xa2\xbd\xc6C\xd1\xcf\x8d$P`\xb9\xad/\x7f\x93+\x82\xd3\xaa\xdex\x03\xc5\xcd\x96\x07\x0fnU-\x89\xdb\xaa[\xee4\rGi\xd5"O\xdc\xaa\x85Y\x9c\xa4i\xb2?B\x8d\xf1)\xdaMPe\xec\xb2\xfaZ\xbf.=\xca\xfe\r<\x9c\xe0\xe1~\x7f\x80\x8f\xd4\xe3|\xfb3\x9fv!\xf2\xb0\xf4\xf4\x19k\xb9\x17\xbddnV\xc2o_\xc9\xeb\xd3|\xfd\xfe\xeb\xb9\x85\x05\xfc\xc7\xe8s\xdf\xf9Zt\xe1\xbf\xd4v4\x02\r\x1cG\xc07\xf7m>\xde\xdb\x83\xa6\xb5m\x83\xee\xad\x82M=\x86_\x9d\xd0\xf8\xfb\xaa\xdb\x9e\x88g\xcb\xdd\xec@Ug\xdd6y\xa9\xabnO\x8f\xaf\xf5\'J\xe3\xbf[o~\xf7\x9a\xbf\xf8\xf5\xbb\x05\xa3{\x8a<\xdf\x97/\x7fl\xcd\x01'
```

(Just a short extract)

I already checked the enconding with `r.encoding` and its UTF-8. How can I read the output / change the encoding to something readable?

My headers:

```
normalheaders = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
}
```

my code

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.max_redirects = 999999999

r = s.get(URL,headers=normalheaders)
```

Comment: It can be any of the types you defined on `Accept`

Comment: There's a reasonable chance it's not text. One of these solutions may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python

Comment: The very first byte (`0x13`) is not an UTF-8 character, unless you expect terminal control characters to be received (`0x13` is the UTF-8/ASCII code for "device control 3"). That means the data you receive is the raw data from a binary file. What is the *exact* file you request?

Comment: What's the URL? What are you expecting from the server?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125147/5320906) solve your problem?

Comment: By the way, have you checked the response headers? What information do you get from them?