# Python http request returns meaningless response

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to build a simple web scraper with Python by using the 'cfscrape' and 'requests' modules:

```
import cfscrape
import requests

url = "my-url"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Referer": url,
    "Host": "host",
    "User-Agent": "my-user-agent",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
}

session = requests.session()
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)
r = scraper.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r)
print("******************")
print(r.text)
```

Howerver, what I get is this strange output:

[image]

As you can see, the request returns a successful response (statusCode: 200). However, the response content is completely meaningless.

How can I solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you requesting for? Some sort of binary file?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get a Json file

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the response headers.

Comment: If it's also possible, post the actual URL you are sending a request to, something for people to test against. Looks like what you got was not json, but probably a zip file (with the json inside?)? I think the URL would complete the [mcve].

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125147/5320906) solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide content of `headers` variable. So I just ommited it and run your code against URL wich returns JSON:

```
import cfscrape
import requests

url = "https://api.aktuality.sk/v1.0/tools/namedays"

session = requests.session()
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)
r = scraper.get(url)

print(r)
print("******************")
print(r.text)
```

and I received JSON correctly. I am using:

```
cfscrape-2.1.1 
python 3.8.5
```

but from what you said, you are calling not URL but you are loading JSON data from file, so assumed from picture, what you see is in binary. I think you should read file and then you would get JSON from file. Something like this for local file:

```
import json 
  
# Opening JSON file 
f = open('data.json',) 
  
# returns JSON object as  
# a dictionary 
data = json.load(f) 
  
print(data) 
  
# Closing file 
f.close()
```

Or if it's remote file:

```
import urllib.request, json 

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.aktuality.sk/v1.0/tools/namedays") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)
```