# Python Getting Very Strage Data, how to decode (requests)

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

I use:

```
import time,requests

ts = str(int(time.time()))
         
s = requests.session()

payload = {"email": "jacquelinehoffm.s0.51993@gmail.com","timestamp":ts}

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;Win64) AppleWebkit/536.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4189.82 Safari/537.16',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Origin': 'https://smailpro.com',
  'Referer': 'https://smailpro.com/advanced',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

r = s.post('https://smailpro.com/app/key',json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

And get something like this:

```
♥��^7⌂�3W►��↕�♂r��+G��"�B�7���@♀��fd{^◄��!�◄l4�↑dx2n‼Sda��bd���;L���E�♦����KG�⌂c�{↔�♫*�lӖޡ��n��l���b���k]��z[_�]|����f�ׯ�_�rs��ɭ-�↑yw��ͥ���J�♫6U���dZ?�W��Y'�M�`����=�T�♥�♀6��m1�~�♠����J�Ur��b��b→p�P��M�♫+�YC;▲
♥��W5Uƹ�@r��9o��|
```

how to decode this data? (it must be Object array: {code:200,items:'eyJ0eXA....iOiJKV1',msg:'OK'})

I check:

```
print(r.encoding) # it returns utf-8
```

I use:

```
with open('output.txt','w+',encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write(r.text) # ♥��^7⌂�......o��|

with open('output.txt','+bw',encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write(r.text) # error
```

base64:

```
import base64
res = base64.b64decode(r.text)
print(res) # error
```

encode, decode and r.content is not working

I just dont know how get data...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't recognize the binary; but is this a compressed binary value?  What exactly were you expecting from that request?

Comment: idk but it str, when i try write as binary it create error, mayby this binary in str

Comment: (it must be Object array: {code:200,items:'eyJ0eXA....iOiJKV1',msg:'OK'})

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59124968/5320906) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please delete this line and have another try:

`'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',`

You asked for compressed version, But you didn't decompress it

If it still returns the same response，It may be because the server only provides a compressed version of documentary.

Then do as follows:

Data=gzip.decompress(r.content).decode("utf-8")

Comment: thank yooou! I just was inattentive, its working,
but this is not working (gzip.decompress(r.content).decode("utf-8"))

gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\x03\x8f')